# How to remove included header file in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, header-files

I've included winsock2.h to my project. But there was a lot of errors, so I remove the line (#include <windsock2.h> ) and build the project. However it failed with the same errors that about winsock2.h.

I remove it but still alive there. Why?
How can I remove it completely in Vistual Studio?

### EDIT

** Managed C++/CLI  Form1.h **

```
#include <myCalibration.h>

namespace CppCLR_WinformsProjekt {
using namespace System;
using namespace System::ComponentModel;
using namespace System::Collections;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
using namespace System::Data;
using namespace System::Drawing;
using namespace System::Threading;
using namespace System::IO;

public ref class Form1 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
{
public:
Form1(void)
{
InitializeComponent();
}
protected:

~Form1()
{
if (components)
{
delete components;
}
}
}
```

** Unmanaged myCalibration.h>**

```
#pragma once

#ifdef DLL_CALIBRATION_EXPORTS
#define CALI_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define CALI_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

#ifndef MYCALIBRATION_H
#define MYCALIBRATION_H

#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip> 
#include <fstream>
#include <math.h>
#include <io.h>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

class CALI_API myCalibration {
#define CALIB_RADIANS 0
#define CALIB_DEGREES 1

public:
    myCalibration();
    myCalibration(int imgRows, int imgCols, int chessBoardRows, int chessBoardCols, int rotation_num, int translation_num, int cam_num);
~myCalibration();
}
```

> I called unmanaged c++ functions from C++/CLI. First I built a
> unmanaged c++ project to make .dll file. And then, run C++/CLI project
> but it failed due to <winsock2.h>. There are errors:

- E1986 an ordinary pointer to a C++/CLI ref class or interface class
  is not allowed winsock2
- C2872 'IServiceProvider': ambiguous symbol
- C2371 'Iserviceprovider' redefinition different basic types

So, I just gave up to use <winsock2.h> and wanted to find other socket programming library. And I deleted #include <WinSock2.h> this line and run the projects again. But there were still same errors.
I've cleaned projects and entire solution and built again but the same errors.

If you have any idea to use <WinSock2.h> for this project, or to remove completely included <WinSock2.h> from the project, please let me know.

Thank you.

Comment: Clean solution or rebuild

Comment: Ehh. 1) post the exact errors if you want us to be able to help you with them. 2) either you need `winsock2.h` or you do not, which is it?

Comment: Are you using git, maybe you haven't added that change to your commit, and your project is being build with the previous version of the file?

Comment: Don't just remove `#include` directives because you thought they didn't belong. If you're using functions defined in that header you *must* include it, and you should also explain the *exact errors* you're getting.

Comment: Perhaps winsock2.h is not the header you needed. Perhaps your code has a huge list of errors whether or not winsock2 is included and you simply didn't notice the change. Perhaps the gods seek to destroy you and are first driving you mad. Hard to say without a good example that demonstrates your problem. Consider crafting an [mre]. If that doesn't help you solve the problem, add the MRE to the question.

Comment: @JesperJuhl 1) I edited the question. 2) I want to use it but I don't think I can use it for c++/cli project. So I will not use it.

Comment: @tadman  I edited the question. I didn't use functions I just added header file. Thank you.

Comment: @SoonmyunJang Your original question never mentioned c++/cli. That changes things. Why didn't you mention that up-front?